# jquery mobile popup shows a black background on device

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I'm using jquery mobile & phonegap to create an app.
jqm version 1.3.1, currently in testing my app with an android device
i'v created  a simple popup (code taken from jqm web site) 
and the popup shows correctly on my pc (page gets opacity) but on the android device the popup is shown different,
the background page looks like it has a black background, but when i scroll (yes i can scroll when the popup is still opend) some of the background looks ok with an opacity, similar to how it looks on my pc.

Any ideas on what is the reason?
10x

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for android sdk 17 (not for older versions which I tested). 
Even though this answer might be to late for this questioner, it may help someone else.

My solution:
In your android manifest, switch *android:anyDensity="true"* to

```
android:anyDensity="false"
```

Regards, miweiss